# Constraintserror - RenderBox was not laid out - Flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm getting constraintserrors with the message saying the RenderBox was not laid out. I think it has something to do with the expanded in the Column and the Column doesn't know what to do.

The problem doesn't exist when I have one card. The problem comes when I have multiple cards in a ListView.

Hope someone can help me out. Thanks a lot!

```
Container(
  decoration: const BoxDecoration(
    color: Colors.white,
  ),
  child: Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
    children: [
      Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              width: 35,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.grey[100],
                borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
                  topLeft: Radius.circular(15),
                  topRight: Radius.circular(15),
                ),
              ),
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Container(
                    height: 75,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.cyan[600],
                      borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(15)),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(child: Container())
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      const SizedBox(
        width: 25,
      ),
      Expanded(
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            const SizedBox(
              height: 12,
            ),
            Text(
              "07:30",
              style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                textStyle: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline6?.copyWith(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 8,
            ),
            Wrap(
              children: [
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 8, 12, 0),
                  child: Text(
                    'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed egestas pretium dui eu feugiat. Cras sodales mauris arcu, egestas vulputate risus mattis a. Fusce quis sem quis eros convallis ornare. Sed efficitur enim id nunc lacinia, ',
                    style: GoogleFonts.poppins(textStyle: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyMedium),
                    maxLines: 7,
                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                    textAlign: TextAlign.justify,
                    softWrap: true,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            const Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 8, 12, 0),
              child: Image(
                image: AssetImage('assets/cartrouble.jpg'),
                fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 8,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      )
    ],
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrapping the Row with IntrinsicHeight widget solved my problem.
Also had to set an exact height.